# Why didn't Tony Stark use this system earlier?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, spider-man-far-from-home

In *Spiderman: Far from Home*, we see Tony give some of his technology to Peter Parker, specifically:

> A massive, space-based swarm of killer robots, controllable through the Edith interface.

It seems that this system would have been very helpful, especially at the end of Endgame. Tony clearly didn't make it between Endgame and Far from Home. Are we given any indication as to why it is left unused until then?

Comment: Maybe it was in an early stage of development when he died and was completed later. He owns a company, he doesn't need to do everything himself. I don't know how much later Far from home takes place.

Comment: @FabianRöling. Possible, but unlikely, because Tony seemed pretty insistent that only Peter have access to EDITH. His company also stopped making weapons in Iron Man 1.

Comment: @BillThePlatypus Stark said in Iron Man 1 that his company was getting out of the weapons *business*, not 'no longer making weapons'. In other words, they didn't stop making weapons; they just stopped selling them. Where do you think all the Iron Man suits and ammo for them come from. Most likely Stark Enterprises only makes weapons and ammo for SHIELD after The Avengers. And after we see EDITH for the first time, it's very clear Stark's and/or his company have been *very* busy with continuing with his whole 'suit of armor around the world' mantra.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Are we given any indication as to why it is left unused until then?

### No

It's questionable as to whether the security drones would have been effective against Thanos' forces.

Certainly, assuming they were available, they would have been completely ineffective against Thanos' spaceship not to mention massively outgunned.

Then again, the climatic battle in *Endgame* is **only a few minutes long** and Tony has other things on his mind. Whether the drones (if available) could have deorbited in time to take part is debatable.

Comment: FFH seems to show them being pretty quick, but maybe that is just the editing. Although I guess they did have a pretty large army themselves.